# What is the font used in the Backbone.js Logo?

Tags: typography, font-identification

Trying to identify the font used in the Backbone.js logo:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Actually, according to an email received by Michael Nieling from Ocupop, Inc, the creator of the Backbone.js logo, the font used is [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans).

Here is a screenshot of the Email:

[image: Email from creator of Backbone JS]

Comment: To be a bit more specific, it's the "Light" cut of Open Sans with reduced/negative tracking/letterspacing.

Answer (score 1):

The font name is [**Core Humanist Sans Light**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fonts-by-alex/core-humanist-sans/light/) and this is not a free font, and the letter "K" and "J" are special among other fonts. Navigate to see the Glyphs character for this font, here is the [link](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fonts-by-alex/core-humanist-sans/light/glyphs.html).

Comment: I think this is be a slight modification of Core Humanist Sans Light - that font is rounded while this has sharp corners. I can't see any non-rounded variant ([Core Sans](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/s-core/core-sans/) is completely different) and other details look to be exactly the same, so I'd guess this was either modified, or is a variant on Core Humanist Sans that hasn't yet been published.

Answer (score 1):

For a free font that matches, you could try [Lato](http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/). (Also in Google Fonts.) As Bala says, the K and J are different.

[image: lato and screenshot]